# How to make Android Unity C# Revmob Ads Appear on the Top of the Screen Instead of the Bottom

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, banner, revmob

The title says it all, right now the ads(by default)are on the bottom of the screen and I want them to be on the top. This is SDK 9.0.0.

I don't know if this script matters, but this activates when triggered.

```js
 public void cargarBanner()
 {
  #if UNITY_EDITOR
  Debug.Log("cargarBanner Revmob.");
  #elif UNITY_ANDROID
  revmob.CreateBanner (RevMob.Position.TOP, 0, 0, Screen.width, 55);
  //revmob.CreateBanner();
  #endif
  //revmob.CreateBanner (RevMob.Position.TOP, 0, 0, Screen.width, 55);
 }
```

RevMobAndroidBanner

```js
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

#if UNITY_ANDROID
public class RevMobAndroidBanner : RevMobBanner {
 private AndroidJavaObject javaObject;

 public RevMobAndroidBanner(AndroidJavaObject activity, AndroidJavaObject listener, RevMob.Position position, int x, int y, int w, int h, AndroidJavaObject session) {
  this.javaObject = session;
  this.javaObject.Call("createBanner", activity, listener, (int)position, x, y, w, h);
 }
 
 public override void Show() {
  Debug.Log("BCRS showBanner");
  this.javaObject.Call("showBanner");
    }

    public override void Hide() {
  Debug.Log("BCRS hideBanner");
  this.javaObject.Call("hideBanner");
    }

 public override void Release() {
  Debug.Log("BCRS releaseBanner");
  this.javaObject.Call("releaseBanner");
 }
}
#endif
```

RevMobAndroid

```js
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Collections.Generic;


#if UNITY_ANDROID
public class RevMobAndroid : RevMob {
 private AndroidJavaObject session;

 public RevMobAndroid(string appId, string gameObjectName) {
  this.gameObjectName = gameObjectName;
  AndroidJavaClass unityRevMobClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.revmob.unity.UnityRevMob");
  this.session = unityRevMobClass.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("start",
                                                                RevMobAndroid.CurrentActivity(),
                                                                appId,
                                                                "unity-android",
                                                                REVMOB_VERSION,
                                                                 new AndroidJavaObject("com.revmob.unity.RevMobAdsUnityListener", gameObjectName, "session"));
 }


 public static AndroidJavaObject CurrentActivity() {
  AndroidJavaClass unityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
  return unityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
 }

 public override bool IsDevice() {
  return (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android);
 }  
      
  private AndroidJavaObject adUnitWrapperCall(string methodName, string placementId, string adUnit) {
  if (placementId == null) {
   placementId = "";
  }
  AndroidJavaObject publisherListener = CreateRevMobListener(this.gameObjectName, adUnit);
  AndroidJavaObject obj = this.session.Call<AndroidJavaObject>(methodName, CurrentActivity(), placementId, publisherListener);
  return obj;
 }

 private AndroidJavaObject CreateRevMobListener(String gameObjectName, String adUnityType) {
  return new AndroidJavaObject("com.revmob.unity.RevMobAdsUnityListener", gameObjectName, adUnityType);
 }

 public override void PrintEnvironmentInformation() {
  session.Call("printEnvironmentInformation", CurrentActivity());
 }

 public override void SetTestingMode(RevMob.Test test) {
  session.Call("setTestingMode", (int)test);
 }

 public override void SetTimeoutInSeconds(int timeout) {
  session.Call("setTimeoutInSeconds", timeout);
 }

 public override RevMobFullscreen ShowFullscreen(string placementId) {
  return new RevMobAndroidFullscreen(this.adUnitWrapperCall("showFullscreen", placementId, "Fullscreen"));
 }

 public override RevMobFullscreen CreateFullscreen(string placementId) {
  if (!IsDevice ()) return null;
  AndroidJavaObject javaObject = this.adUnitWrapperCall("createFullscreen", placementId, "Fullscreen");
  return new RevMobAndroidFullscreen(javaObject);
 }

 public override RevMobFullscreen CreateVideo(string placementId) {
  if (!IsDevice ()) return null;
  AndroidJavaObject javaObject = this.adUnitWrapperCall("createVideo", placementId, "Fullscreen");
  return new RevMobAndroidFullscreen(javaObject);
 }

 public override RevMobFullscreen CreateRewardedVideo(string placementId) {
  if (!IsDevice ()) return null;
  AndroidJavaObject javaObject = this.adUnitWrapperCall("createRewardedVideo", placementId, "Fullscreen");
  return new RevMobAndroidFullscreen(javaObject);
 }

 public override RevMobBanner CreateBanner(RevMob.Position position, int x, int y, int w, int h) {
  return (IsDevice()) ? new RevMobAndroidBanner(CurrentActivity(), CreateRevMobListener(this.gameObjectName, "Banner"), position, x, y, w, h, session) : null;
 }

 public override void ShowBanner(RevMob.Position position, int x, int y, int w, int h) {
  if (!IsDevice ()) return;
  this.session.Call("showBanner", CurrentActivity(), CreateRevMobListener(this.gameObjectName, "Banner"), (int)position, x, y, w, h);
 }

 public override void HideBanner() {
  this.session.Call("hideBanner", CurrentActivity());
 }

 public override RevMobLink OpenLink(string placementId) {
  return new RevMobAndroidLink(this.adUnitWrapperCall("openLink", placementId, "Link"));
 }

 public override RevMobLink CreateLink(string placementId) {
  if (!IsDevice ()) return null;
  AndroidJavaObject javaObject = this.adUnitWrapperCall("createLink", placementId, "Link");
  return new RevMobAndroidLink(javaObject);
 }



 public override RevMobPopup ShowPopup(string placementId) {
  return new RevMobAndroidPopup(this.adUnitWrapperCall("showPopup", placementId, "Popup"));
 }

 public override RevMobPopup CreatePopup(string placementId) {
  return new RevMobAndroidPopup(this.adUnitWrapperCall("createPopup", placementId, "Popup"));
 }
}
#endif
```